# No entry sign in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Does anybody know what this sign means?

[image]

Comment: Have you googled this? This doesn't seem like a question for SO.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe.aspx

Comment: Not sure why this has so many down votes. Seems a legit question to me and the icon isn't in MSDN link so not sure if that's answers the question.

Comment: Yes. I didn't found any answer, also in the link above

Comment: this is a private member

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev How would we know that looking at the documentation? MSDN agrees its a member, but private is shown as a lock icon all the way back to 2003

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko - The question is poor because the OP did not say where they are seeing that icon (looks like in the debugger watch window) and what class that property is a part of.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at a [Debug Watch or Quick Watch Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx) similar to this one:

[image]

The stop sign is added when the member you're watching is marked as `internal`. Each [access modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) has its own indicator. As you can see from the picture and the code that belongs to it:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var test = new Test();
     // put breakpoint here
 }

public class Test : TestBase
{
    internal int SomeNumber;
    protected int FooNumber;
}

public abstract class TestBase
{
    internal int AbstractInternalSomeInt;
    public int OtherInt;
    private byte SomeByte;

}
```

Notice that in the class view and in the Solution Explorer the symbol for internal members is different, it shows a heart instead:

[image: solutio explorer and class view]

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post when searching for "visual studio solution explorer no entry symbol". In my case the symbol was presented when using the file view of solution explorer rather than class view. It turned out this was because my gitignore file had an exclusion to all files "*.userprefs" and I'd added project called "userprefs" - what are the odds!

Easy way to fix - right click the files in solution explorer and choose "Add ignored file to source control". Would be worth checking that this makes the desired change to the .gitignore file

Answer (score 0):

In files view, I think it indicates the file is excluded from the build.
Maybe (as in my case) the file is directly included into something that is part of the build.
Look at properties > Excluded from build